# AS3: How to remove a list item at a particular index

Tags: actionscript-3

Kindly help on how to remove a list item at a particular index of the List component in Flash as I couldn't find any help on it adobe docs. Only addItem is mentioned, what about all other methods applicable to the list component like in any other language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Arraycollection to bind your data with List in flash. Changes occurred in array collection will reflect in list view too. You can use addItem & removeItemAt(index) from data provider, which will reflect in your List VIew

```
[Bindable]var MyArr : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection() ; 
Assign values to this arraycollection.....
<s:List x="170" y="146" dataProvider="{myArr}"></s:List>
use..
myArr.addItem("Hello");   // to add something
myArr.removeItemAt(0);    // to remove something from a Array
```